# Does res.write in nodejs blocks the server from responding to other request till you call res.end?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is the time between res.write and res.end is blocked from serving other requests? I have a simple node server which does red.write on request and res.end after a setTimeout of 5 secs. During this time i hit the server from different tab I start getting response only after first request is done? Why is it harrowing?

**Update:**

Code I that I am running,

This is the code I am running,

```
 var http = require('http');
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {
        response.setHeader('Connection', 'Transfer-Encoding');
        response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
        response.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');

        response.write('hello');

        setTimeout(function() {
            response.write(' world!');
            response.end();
        }, 10000);

    }).listen(8888);
```

Comment: Browsers limit the number of concurrent connections to a single server to about 6 or so. If you delay sending a response and you've just hit that limit, any new requests (from another tab, say) may block until the delayed request is sent. Try testing from another browser (and you'll find it _won't_ block).

Comment: No, why would it? Each request has its own response, and is served separately. The whole point of node is its non-blocking nature.

Comment: Use logging on the server side to see when you receive the requests and when you respond to them. That should sort out any problems with the connection.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell anything specific when you don't show the actual code. I'm not entirely sure what you are asking about. Do you mean that you don't get the message passed to `res.write` until the `res.end` is called in a given request or do you mean that your next request doesn't start until the first one finishes?

I am guessing what you may be experiencing, I hope it will get you on the right track. Consider this simple program:

```
var app = require('express')();
app.get('/:n/:t', (req, res) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < req.params.n; i++) res.write('x');
  setTimeout(() => res.end(), req.params.t);
});
app.listen(5000);
```

When you run it you can connect with curl to e.g.:

- http://localhost:5000/5/1000

to write 5 characters with `res.write` and call `res.end` after 1000 milliseconds, like this:

```
curl http://localhost:5000/5/1000
```

You will indeed not see those 5 characters after the delay.

You can try with more characters:

```
curl http://localhost:5000/1000/1000
```

With 1000 characters I still don't get them before the timeout.

But with even more, like 3000:

```
curl http://localhost:5000/3000/1000
```

I get some characters immediately, then I wait for the timeout, and then I get the rest of them.

That's because the characters are not displayed before the buffer is filled or the connection is closed. But those characters are being sent as soon as possible which can be seen with `tcpdump`. It's just that curl is doing some buffering here.

### Update

You posted your code, so try this:

```
var http = require('http');
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {
        response.setHeader('Connection', 'Transfer-Encoding');
        response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
        response.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');

        response.write('hello\n');

        setTimeout(function() {
            response.write(' world!');
            response.end();
        }, 10000);

    }).listen(8888);
```

I added `\n` after `hello`. Now at least `curl` shows hello before the timout. See:

```
curl http://localhost:8888
```

Is this what you were looking for?

### Better example

Check out this program:

```
var app = require('express')();
app.get('/:n', (req, res) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => res.write(req.params.n|0 ? '.\n' : '.'), 100 * i);
  }
  setTimeout(() => res.end('\n'), 1500);
});
app.listen(5000);
```

And try those two invocations of `curl`:

```
# dots with no newlines:
curl http://localhost:5000/0

# dots with newlines:
curl http://localhost:5000/1
```

Comment: What do you mean by characters will not be sent before buffer is filled? Whats the expected buffer size to be filled?

Comment: Not exactly. Did you try hitting the server from two different browser tabs concurrently? In that case I get first line itself in the second tab after the first tab is completely done ie. after first timeout.